# Can you add friends on Pokemon Quest mobile?

Tags: pokemon-quest

Is the mobile version of Pokemon Quest purely single player?

Answer (score 1):

From what I have found from quick searches, there are no friends or multiplayer, it's only a single player game.

Comment: Can confirm from finishing the game; it is single-player only